# AWS and TLS Certificates

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, amazon-iam, aws-certificate-manager

Is there any way of using TLS certificates in AWS, under the following conditions

- Without first importing  the certificate and the private key, in clear text, into AWS Certificate Manager or AIM
- Without first creating a Root Certificate in AWS Certificate Manager

BR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do it directly into each server by yourself, with the implication that you will need to take care of the renewal, logs, and any other security concern about the management of the certificate